# Age in days in c

Tags: c

`input: 800(days)`

```
output:
2 years
2 months
10 days
```

Conditions are required to match: `only to facilitate the calculation, consider the whole year with 365 days and 30 days every month. In the cases of test there will never be a situation that allows 12 months and some days, like 360, 363 or 364.`

I have solved this problem in this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int
main(void){

int n;
double years;
double months;
double days;
scanf("%d",&n);

years = n / 365.0;

double fractional, integer;

//To split the floating value(years) into the integer and decimal
fractional = modf (years, &integer);

//To get months from here
months = 12.1666666667 * fractional;

//To take nearest 8 digits after the decimal
double d = round (months * 100000000.0)/100000000.0;

double fractionalUpdate, integerUpdate;

//To split the floating value(months) into the integer and decimal
fractionalUpdate = modf (d,&integerUpdate);

//To get days from here
days = (365 * fractionalUpdate) / 12.1666666667;
printf("%g years\n",integer);
printf("%g months\n",integerUpdate);
printf("%g days\n",days);

}
```

My purpose is: Would you propose any simplification from this solution? Would I face any kind of problem for some conditions?

Comment: What are the expected inputs? What should the desired behaviour be when unexpected input is encountered?

Comment: What kind of year always has 365.0 days?

Comment: Mandatory watching: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: @TobySpeight, Sorry for the late reply sir, I have updated my question regarding conditions.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Ok Sir, I am going to watch it.

Comment: @Mast Sorry for the late reply sir. I did not check in this solution when unexpected input is encountered. Would you please explain how can I handle the situation when  unexpected input is encountered?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @Reinderien Obviously not.

Answer (score 3):

### Intractability

Think hard about what's happening here - you're asking that the user provide a timedelta or time interval that is divorced from absolute time, e.g. 800 days. However, you do not ask that it be specified as "800 days in 2020" or "800 days in 1974". So:

It is impossible to map a number of days to a number of years, months and days unless, in practice, you ask for either a start point or end point of the given period.

Ignoring daylight savings time, unequal-length months, leap years etc. it's not even exactly possible to map an arbitrary interval to a count of hours, minutes and seconds, because leap seconds are also sometimes introduced, though this effect is minor.

Long story short, for this program to produce meaningful results, ask for "number of days past a given timestamp".

Comment: Sorry for the late reply sir. I have updated my question. I hope now everything is going to be clear. Check out the 'Conditions are required to match' section.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just invented the 12x30 + 5 calender: this gives you a fractional month (5 extra days in between the years), and your seasons will drift 1 day every 4 years.

```
365
1 years
0 months
0 days

364
0 years
12 months
4 days
```

12 months, 4 days is quite wrong.

There is a simpler solution. I think it does make sense to figure out how much 1000 days is in larger units. These "years" and "months" have an average value, based on two facts: earth takes 365.25 days around the sun, and we divide a year into twelve months.

```
365
years: 0 months: 11 days 30
366
years: 1 months: 0 days 0
```

Having a non-integer days-per-year also helps conceptually: either you are below or above.

So for 800 I get 2 days less than your solution:

```
800
years: 2 months: 2 days 8
```

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    void main(void) {
        double dpy = 365.25;         // a bit less, actually
        int mpy = 12;
        double dpm = dpy / mpy;
    
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n);
    
        int years  = n / dpy;
        int months = n / dpm - years*mpy;
        int days   = n - years*dpy - months*dpm;

        printf("years: %d months: %d days %d\n", years, months, days);
    }
```

An illustration:

```
    800-365-365-30-30
    10
    800-365.25-365.25-30.5-30.5
    8.50
```

The numbers are not precise. Still it means you have to say

`800 days = 2 years, 2 months, 2 days and 12 hours`

which is quite paradoxical on first view. The way I started my program I think I lost these hours forever...

---

With `dpy = 365.2425` I also get 400:0:0 for 146097 days. With the full quarter it was 399:11:27. This 4-100-400-rule can get you far. And  `.2425` is not a funny fraction, but very logical:

```
1/4 =    0.25, minus 1/100 is 0.24
1/400= 0.0025
Add:
 0.24
+0.0025
```

**HAPPY NEW 365.2425 2021**

Comment: Sorry for the late reply sir. 'I think you just invented the 12x30 + 5 calender:'. Your assumption is hundred percent right. I have updated my question. You  can check the 'Conditions are required to match' section.

Comment: The old Egyptians had a 360+5 days year. I assume they handled it more elegant than that. What is your definition of year? Is the title not a bit misleading?

Answer (score 2):

> Would you propose any simplification from this solution?

C has `mktime()` to help convert days into year, month, day.

Consider using standard library functions.  OP's approach is fragile.

I see this goes against the task's "only to facilitate the calculation, consider the whole year with 365 days and 30 days every month", yet I see that requirement as counter idiomatic.  Rather I encourage date manipulation code should consider standard functions first.

> Would I face any kind of problem for some conditions?

Usually using integer math is better for an integer problem, rather than having to cope with various subtleties of floating point math.  Research `%, /` and maybe even `div()`.

---

Slight variation occur depending on your reference date.

For "Age", I'd use one's birthday as the reference date.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

// Return error flag
int days_to_ymd(int *year, int *month, int *day, int days) {
  // TBD, extend functionality to handle negative days.
  if (days < 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  const struct tm ref_2001Jan1 = {.tm_year = 2001 - 1900, .tm_mon = 1 - 1,
      .tm_mday = 1,   // Maye use subject's birthday?
      .tm_hour = 12}; // Use Noon to avoid DST and time zone shift issues
  struct tm ts = ref_2001Jan1;

  // Add the days
  ts.tm_mday += days;

  // mktime() re-adjusts it members to their primary range. 
  if (mktime(&ts) == -1) {
    return 1;
  }

  *year = ts.tm_year - ref_2001Jan1.tm_year;
  // More code needed if ref month is not January to handle wrap around.
  *month = ts.tm_mon - ref_2001Jan1.tm_mon;
  // More code needed if ref day is not 1st to handle wrap around.
  *day = ts.tm_mday - ref_2001Jan1.tm_mday;
  return 0;
}
```

Test

```
void test_days_to_ymd(int days) {
  int year, month, day;
  int err = days_to_ymd(&year, &month, &day, days);
  if (err) {
    printf("Error: %d days\n", days);
  } else {
    printf("%9d days --> %3d years, %2d months, %2d days\n", days, year, month,
        day);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  test_days_to_ymd(0);
  test_days_to_ymd(31);
  test_days_to_ymd(365);
  test_days_to_ymd(365 * 4 + 1);
  test_days_to_ymd(27375 /* Average lifespan (est) */);
  test_days_to_ymd(100 * (365 * 4 + 1) - 3);
}
```

Output

```
        0 days -->   0 years,  0 months,  0 days
       31 days -->   0 years,  1 months,  0 days
      365 days -->   1 years,  0 months,  0 days
     1461 days -->   4 years,  0 months,  0 days
    27375 days -->  74 years, 11 months, 13 days
   146097 days --> 400 years,  0 months,  0 days
```